# White color icon.png to blue color icon.png (html/css)

Tags: html, css

White icon.png to color blue icon.png (html/css)

Before it is white color icon.png. After it has also white color. How to make, example, blue color icon.png?

html:

```
<img src="icon.png" class="icon1">
```

css:

```
icon1 {
 background: url(icon.png);
 color: blue;
}
//not working
```

or this

html:

```
<img src="icon.png" class="icon2">
```

css:

```
icon2 {
 color: blue;
}
//also not working
```

Can you show me how? Not photoshop, only html and css.

Comment: share the icon .

Comment: At first place `color:blue;` is css to set color of text, not background... `background-color` is what you need, but if "icon" in your png file doesn't have `transparent` background, you can't change background color of your `img`... You can, but without any visible  effect... btw. your first try `background: url(icon.png)` doesn't have any sense because you showing that picture using `img`.

Comment: Similar https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png. Always white/black color. Not ex. blue.

Comment: With css you can't change that black color of image... image isn't black/white... provided image, by you, is black on transparent background.. try, for example, `img:hover {background-color:blue;}` and you'll see changes... but, color of image you can't change... you can see, let's call it, solution provided by @pid

Answer (score 2):

possible with `mask-image`

as you can see

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue; /* select your want color */
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png);
  mask-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png);
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: There is browser support for `mask-image` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image ... There is users who doesn't allow every day updating they browsers (because it' mostly unreal updates)... I'm one of them... So, using FF below v53 there is only orange box and nothing else... btw. there is still a lot of users, and yes, companies, who still use IE... it's not cross browser solution.

Comment: @nelek I don't agree! Web browsers like Chrome and Firefox have an "Auto-update" enable by default. Other browsers are updated together with the operation system. Keep browsers updated is the best way to stay safe!
The most users keep their browsers updated.

Comment: Yes, but You can turn off that auto-update... btw. why to keep browser always updated? That sounds me like every year new iPho*e... :D ;) My FF 49, yeap 48, still perfectly working... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Bootstrap and glyphicons. With Bootstrap you'll be able to have inline icons by using HTML like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
```

There are ways to color these icons white on dark backgrounds.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) is a list of supported icons.