# Reduce size (mask-image). Can you help me?

Tags: html, css, png, jpeg, gif

Color is fixed [White color icon.png to blue color icon.png (html/css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977081/white-color-icon-png-to-blue-color-icon-png-html-css/53981508), but minimum (or maximum) how to do?

```
div {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 50px;
 padding: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 right: 50px;
 background-size: 50px;
 mask-size: 50px; /* not supported by Chrome */
 -webkit-mask-image: 50px; /* also not supported by Chrome */

 background-color: blue; /* select your want color */
 -webkit-mask-image: 
 url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png);
 mask-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png);
 mask-repeat:no-repeat;
 -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}

<div></div>
```

How to reduce size?

```
margin: 50px; padding: 50px;
```

no

```
left: 50px; right: 50px; top: 50px; bottom: 50px;
```

no

```
background-size: 50px;
```

no

```
mask-size: 50px;
```

no, not supported by Chrome

```
webkit-mask-size: 50px;
```

no, also not supported by Chrome

```
width: 50px; height: 50px;
```

and no

What to do?

Comment: you want to reduce the size of the mask or the size of the whole icon?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mask you can rely on `mix-blend-mode` then you can easily adjust the image as a simple background:

```css
div.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png) center/cover;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also change the color of only a part of the image by adjusting the pseudo element:

```css
div.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/54/54591.png) center/cover;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```